Tilde "~" has moved in the spanish keyboard
After upgrading to xubuntu 24.04, the "tilde" character has moved from "AltCr + ¡" to "AltCr + 4". I am using a Spanish keyboard Generic 105-key PC
Is there any way to recover the previous key combination?
Thanks.
